# How to detect page is updated after change product options?(Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I am working on a Chrome extension to be used on Amazon.

I inserted **blue** button on the right panel when page is loaded.

As you know when we select product options(style, color, size ...), some contents such as the right panel are re-rendered. And my **blue** button disappears(maybe).

[image]
I inserted blue button like below;

```
$(window).ready(function () {
  $('#atc-declarative').before("<img id='addToCartMM' src='chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id + "/blue.png'>");

  // select buttons in style-list and add click event.
  $('#variation_style_name .a-button-text').click(function() {
    // insert button again.
  });
  ...
}
```

How can I detect when some contents are updated after select product options?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @Michal Thanks. I tried before. And it was failed. Which types of mutations should I use?

Comment: It depends. But I guess if whole right panel is being re-rendered, observe for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit/childList mutation and if any is detected append the button again.

Comment: @Michal Thanks again. But In my memory, callback was called too many times(over 1k in a short time). Because when each child is added, it will be called. How can I call only once? Shall I use debounce?

Comment: Did you choose the right panel container element as a target when using MutationObserver? Also you need to ignore mutation when the button is appened again to avoid cycle.

Comment: @Michal Thanks. I solved my issue. :)